# ListBox to Excel

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel, listbox, export

Ok, so I have a class, customer, that I use to process data, and then add to a list box, like below:

```
   //Submit data from current form         
   customer aCustomer = new customer(comboBox1.Text, textBox1.Text, ChannelSelecBox.Text,
     PurchaserTextBox.Text, NameTextBox.Text, emailTextBox.Text, AddressTextBox.Text, StateBox.Text,
     PayMethodDropDown.Text, Prod1Num.Value.ToString(), Prod2Num.Value.ToString(), 
    Prod3Num.Value.ToString(), Prod4Num.Value.ToString(), Prod5Num.Value.ToString(), 
    Prod6Num.Value.ToString(), SubTData.Text, DiscountTextBox.Text, TaxData.Text, CommentTextBox.Text, 
    ShipData.Text, TotalData.Text);

           // Add aCustomer to ListBox
           Orders.Items.Add(aCustomer);
```

I have a string override so that the listbox just displays the purchaser and the date.
Now I want to take all the orders entered into the list box and put, most of, this data into an excel spreadsheet, each into it's own column. How could I do this?

If you need more information or to see more of my code, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

try the following;

```
object oOpt = System.Reflection.Missing.Value; //for optional arguments
Excel.Application oXL = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbooks oWBs = oXL.Workbooks;
Excel.Workbook oWB = oWBs.Add(Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
Excel.Worksheet oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

//outputRows is a List<List<object>>
int numberOfRows = outputRows.Count;
int numberOfColumns = outputRows.Max(list => list.Count);

Excel.Range oRng = 
    oSheet.get_Range("A1", oOpt)
        .get_Resize(numberOfRows, numberOfColumns);

object[,] outputArray = new object[numberOfRows, numberOfColumns];

for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < outputRows[row].Count; col++)
    {
        outputArray[row, col] = outputRows[row][col];
    }
}

oRng.set_Value(oOpt, outputArray);

oXL.Visible = true;
```

more details can be found at http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-create-excel.htm

Comment: Wenman-Vateson: thanks, I'll try this out and report back later

Answer (score 0):

Use CSV as file format, not XLS. Excel is a pain. Especially when reading from XLS. Some incorrect cell formatting and you sometimes get the value, but sometimes not. Even in same file. Personal experience.

Comment: if I were to do it your way, how would I do that?